# How to use promises in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am pulling in multiple divs via multiple ajax calls. Before the first ajax call I want to display a loading spinner. Once all the divs (which will take an unknown time) have loaded I want to sort them. Finally I want to remove the loading spinner layer.

I think I need to use promises for this (because of the multiple ajax calls) however I don't understand how to implement promises - could someone please show me how to write the promises and if I need to add code to my functions relating to that what to add please?

Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#refresh_view", function(){

    start_spinner();
    load_all_divs(list_of_ids_to_loop_over);

    // once the above is complete
    re_order_divs();

    // once the above is complete
    end_spinner();

});


load_all_divs(list_of_ids_to_loop_over) {

    $.each(list_of_application_ids.split(','), function(index){
        do_ajax_call_for_this_one_item(this)
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading the divs with jQuery's `$.ajax` (or `$.get`, etc.), you can use jQuery's [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when), since those already return jQuery `jqXHR` objects, which are promise-like:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(/*...*/),
    $.ajax(/*...*/),
    $.ajax(/*...*/)
)
.done(() => {
    // All done
})
.fail(error => {
    // Something went wrong
});
```

If you're using a moderately up-to-date version of jQuery, you can also use the standard [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), since `jqXHR` objects in modern versions of jQuery are *thenable*. `Promise.all` accepts an array:

```
Promise.all([
    $.ajax(/*...*/),
    $.ajax(/*...*/),
    $.ajax(/*...*/)
])
.then(() => {
    // All done
})
catch(error => {
    // Something went wrong
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The ajax calls are in an .each loop inside load_all_divs() 

`load_all_divs(list_of_ids_to_loop_over) {

    $.each(list_of_application_ids.split(','), function(index){
        do_ajax_call_for_this_one_item(this)
    });
};`

so how would I do my promise please? Thank you for your help, I think I get the concept of promises but I don't understand where / how I create the promise, update it when things are done, and make the next thing that needs to run wait until that promise is done. Once I've got my head around that I think I need to understand how to chain them!

Comment: @happysailingdude - Save the results of the calls in an array and use `Promise.all` on the array: `Promise.all(list_of_application_ids.split(',').map(do_ajax_call_for_this_one_item)).then(function() { /* ...all done... */ }).catch(function(error) { /* ...handle/report error... */});`

Comment: Thanks TJ - unfortunately I don't know how to save results of ajax calls to an array. I was hoping I could leave load_all_divs() as it is because it's far more complex that what is is my code above (but probably add a promise object?) and rewrite the code that fires then the on click event occurs to use promises.. I'm sorry my javascript is rather rudimentary